# How to make a login screen like Facebook app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, authentication, storyboard

How can I make a login screen like the Facebook app with "Email" and "Password" textfields?

[Facebook Login](http://extdesenv.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/facebook-login-ios.png)

I'm really new to iOS programming, sorry if this is an easy question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all you have to understand `UIView`s and `UIViewController`s creation and management.

Then, you could ask your self if you want to create the interface through xib files or programatically. The first way is quite simple. By means of drag and drop operations you could create a user interface in a short time. The second, instead, is more complex for a newbie but I think it could be a valid solution to understand stuffs.

Note that each operation that you do in xib files can be done programatically.

Now, I'll try to explain what elements you need to create that interface.

To create the interface like the following you could create a xib view interface. The view for this interface is the container for your elements. To the container view you could add a `UITableView` with a grouped style. This `UITableView` has 2 rows and each row allows to enter text by means of `UITextField`. To do this, you have to create it programatically. No chance to do it with xib.

Login and signup can be created with two `UIButton`s. To those buttons you need to attach some actions.

Finally the background image could be set programatically as a background image for your container.

This is a simple description on how to create such an interface. Before starting, I suggest you to read some tutorial on how to:

1. Use `UIView` and `UIViewController`
2. Create interface trough xib
3. Interact with interface xib through outlet and actions
4. [Use UITableView and understand its management](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html)
5. [Customize or editing UItableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)
6. Use `UIImageView` and/or `UIImage`

A good starting point for iOS application development could be [www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).

Hope it helps.

Comment: i need to learn all of those things to do the design of the textfields email and password? i thought it was just a grouped table view. i tried to make it a grouped table but i cant see it on the device simulator when i run it

Comment: Follow step 4 if you want to create a tableview first.

Comment: How can achieve the login functionality while doing this way.

Comment: @VineeshTP What do you mean?

Comment: @flexaddicted : Can I login through Facebook by using custom login screen

Comment: @VineeshTP Yes by using their API

Comment: that came in faceboook default login page right ? Can i customize to own textFields for username and password

Answer (score -1):

1)In your Xib file..add an image view..set it to the image you want..that will be background like in the Facebook pic.(blue) and that image should include middle (email and password background) part as well.

2) Drag and drop UITextField on it. Make the background custom.

Answer (score -3):

Since you are new..I will point out the details..and then you search on them that way you will understand better :

*Search on each of these things on google..cant give info for each.*

**1)In your Xib file..add an image view..set it to the image you want..that will be background like in the Facebook pic.(blue)**

**2)The middle part is a UITableViewCell with one section and 2 rows..search on it..**

**3) And the Log in and sign up are UIButtons..add them in xib and make them IBOutlets..again search on it**

Comment: yes, i know point 1 and 3. the only thing that i dont know is the tableview. i dragged a table view to one of my xibs on the storyboard, changed the style of the table to grouped and it looks fine. but if i run, i cant see the cells, just the background of the table.

Comment: search table view..in the documentation..what you have to learn specifically is the tableview delegate and datasource funtion

Comment: You don't need to use a tableview, you can just use UITextFields (see my answer). tableviews can just help with the formatting.

Comment: yeahh..it appears..it will be easier with UITextField..just set it to custom background .