# IOS Facebook Login Screen with Storyboard

Tags: ios, authentication, uitableview

Hello I was searching a lot.
What I was trying to do is built my own Login in Screen as it is done within the facebook app or twitter.
[Dont know what I mean? Check it out](http://extdesenv.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/facebook-login-ios.png)

I was wondering if somebody knows a tutorial or even a sample app that uses the storyboard in order to create that login screen view controller with group prototype cells?

thank you guys a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a login screen like Facebook app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961914/how-to-make-a-login-screen-like-facebook-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with Building a View Controller, loaded a background image and added the [Bottom Cell Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgsP5.png) and 
[Top Cell Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNiub.png)

Then Added the Labels an secure Text to it.

The Image is hard to see its a white Image. Do a right klick an download the image. this works

Answer (score 0):

Use [Parse](http://www.parse.com).

It's as simple as that really...

Parse is an SDK for iOS that allows you to do a whole manner of things, as well as use their awesome free-to-implement package for complete management of user accounts.

The Parse SDK comes with a fully customisable login and sign-up controller that links with an online user database for your app. They have brilliant tutorials, and you can check out their docs [here](https://www.parse.com/docs).

EDIT:

After request, here is the link to a similar SO question with a more login-centric answer:
[How to make a login screen like Facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961914/how-to-make-a-login-screen-like-facebook-app)

Comment: Great! If that helped then I'd appreciate you marking it as the answer :) (only if you feel it is the answer, of course)

Comment: well at least its a solution :=)

Comment: well after looking into it, it will only allow be to login at a cloud server of parse! I want to login at my own web server!

Comment: That wasn't what your question was asking: I offered you a complete solution. I have amended my answer to include a link to an SO question of how to create a lone login screen.

Comment: 4th result on Google then for an in-depth tutorial? http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/03/iphoneios-programming-login-screen-post-data-url-parses-json-response/3/